apache beam - custom golang dataflow application stucked
I am create a straighforward application that load some configurations from MongoDB and start a apache beam pipeline using dataflow runner like this:
func main(){
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://mongodb:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    beam.Init()
    beamPipeline := beam.NewPipeline()
    scope := beamPipeline.Root()

    collection := textio.Read(scope, "gs://mybucket/input.txt")

    ctx := context.Background()
    var transResult beam.PCollection
    // run ParDo functions
    textio.Write(scope, "gs://mybucket/output.txt", collection)

    if err := beamx.Run(ctx, beamPipeline); err != nil {
        panic(errMsg)
    }
}

However, when i run this apache beam pipeline using dataflow runner, the worker doesnt' start because worker try run mongo db code:

PS: this code works using direct runner.
My questions are:

Why is the dataflow runner attempting to run code outside pipeline scope?
If dataflow worker run all code inside the main function, how create a custom application to run dataflow jobs? like start a job when a message come from pub/sub or load custom transformation options from mongodb... like this example

